# Translation of "Robbe"

Tags: word-meaning, translation

While translating some plague documents from the 16th century, I keep coming across the word "Robbe", and I have no idea what it means. It's not in my dictionary, either. Some of the contexts of the word include:

> Sotto pena della vita, & confiscationi, & perdita delle **robbe**.
>
> Corrente sanno intendere, che tutte le **robbe**, & mercantie capaci a retener infettione di peste...\
>
> Corrente no li ammetterà alcuno fia ch’esser si voglia con **robbe**, ne senza se non haverà le sue sede in stampa dai luoghi d’onde verran mentre peto non siano, o vengano da lochi già banditi sotto le pene come di sopra a chi volesse intrar senza fede.

Is "Robbe" simply an archaic term or am I missing something? What does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

It's a central-southern Italy variant of *robe*, the plural form of *roba*, which is a quite generic word meaning more or less “thing, stuff“. Here it seems to refer to “goods”, in general.

(You might have noticed that also in several other words, the orthography used in these sentences would be non-standard for today uses – for instance *infettioni* for *infezioni*, or *lochi* for *luoghi* – , but of course some 500 years ago spelling was far from fixed and codified.)

Answer (score 5):

It's likely a variant of *robe*, [as DaG suggested](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9430/794).

However, for reasons that will soon be apparent, I feel the need to stress the possibility that it might refer not only to "items", "things" in general, but, depending on context (which we don't have), to:

1. Goods
   (possibly in the sense of *all* of one's material possessions)
2. Clothes
3. Merchandise

See this entry [from the Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/roba/):

> 1. [...] Con valore collettivo, il complesso di ciò che si possiede, dei proprî
>      beni, mobili e immobili: ha lasciato ai poveri tutta la sua r.; ha
>      dilapidato tutta la r. ereditata dal padre; Lo villanello a cui la r.
>      manca (Dante); fare danno a qualcuno nella persona e nella r.; fare
>      r., acquistare delle proprietà, e, più genericam., fare, accumulare
>      quattrini: rade volte fa r. chi non ruba (prov.); La r., novella di G.
>      Verga, nella raccolta delle Novelle rusticane (1883), che tratta di un
>      contadino arricchito e divenuto schiavo dei suoi beni. b. Con sign.
>      più partic., i mobili, le masserizie e, in genere, le suppellettili e
>      gli arnesi di casa: tutta la r. di casa è della moglie; e assol.: ha
>      la casa piena di r.; ha tanta r. che non sa dove metterla; caricò la
>      sua r. su un autocarro.

---

> 2. a. Stoffa, tessuto: di che r. è fatto
>      questo vestito?; r. di lana, di cotone, ecc.; r. buona, fine,
>      grossolana, cattiva, che non si ritira. b. Vestito, indumento: lei,
>      che tutta era stracciata, d’alcuna delle sue r. rivestisse
>      (Boccaccio). In alcuni periodi della storia del costume il termine r.
>      (e l’accr. robone) indicò particolari pezzi del vestiario, come
>      mantelli, cappucci, gonnelle; oggi è termine generico per indicare
>      ogni sorta d’indumenti (abiti, biancheria, ecc.), in espressioni come
>      roba da lavare, da bucato, da rammendare; roba d’inverno, d’estate;
>      radunò le sue poche r. in un cassetto, in una sacca. In partic., roba
>      da (o di) camera (calco del fr. robe de chambre), sinon. ormai
>      disusato di veste da camera, vestaglia.

---

> 3. Merce in genere: r.
>      nostrale, estera, comune, rara, a buon mercato, cara, di prima
>      qualità, di scarto; sulle insegne dei rigattieri: si compra e si vende
>      r. usata.

I find the second choice particularly worth of consideration, since burning clothing and bed clothes of people infected by the plague is attested in several places, as a quick search will reveal.

See for example [this link](http://www.shakespearesengland.co.uk/2012/12/09/all-bed-clothes-of-the-infected-to-be-burned/), which, moreover, tells us that the Venetians had reason to look upon clothes with suspect.

> The blankets, matresses, flockbeds, and all bed-clothes of the
>   infected, are to be burned, also leather garments, because they hold
>   the infection very long. Alexander Benedictus reports that in Venice,
>   a flockbed used in a contagious time, was after 7 yeares found in an
>   inward roome, the Mistris of the house commanded the servants to ayre
>   and beat it, whereupon the servants were instantly infected with the
>   pestilence and died.

As a bonus, [here is a 17th century engraving of Hippocrates burning plague clothes](https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/225925/view/hippocrates-ordering-plague-clothes-burnt):

[image: Hippocrates ordering plague clothes burnt]

As a side note, allow me to suggest that you link to the complete text you're working on in the future, or at least provide more context.